how can we get the Actual Uri of an image using ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia
How can we get the Actual Uri of an image using ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia
I am using the compose image picker
val singlePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                    contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(),
                    onResult = { uri -> selectedImageUri = uri }
                )

However the uri that we get is
content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/123456

the actual uri should be
content://media/external/images/media/1000008373` which I want to save in the room database so that it can be used lateron 

how can we get this uri using just ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia

New android versions restrict direct access of files which are not in our app's directory. So you will have to create a bitmap from the uri you are getting here and then you can save it to app's cache directory and perform anything that you want.  OR do you want to download it?
